# Link different data sources in Matlab subplots

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot latitude and longitude data together with another type of data (speed), recorded at every latitude-longitude-point. This is basically equivalent to

```matlab
figure()
subplot(1,2,1); plot(lat,lon);
subplot(1,2,2); plot(t,y);
```

Where all vectors have the same length and `t` is the timestamp in seconds for every recording. I'd love to be able to link the data such that when I highlight data in the first subplot, the corresponding data gets highlighted in the second subplot (and vice versa).

However, because the two subplots don't have a common data source (at least not by name), I struggle to get `linkdata` working.

Here's what I tried (without `linkdata`)

```matlab
function linkedexasmple()
close all

t = linspace(-2,2,100);
lat = sin(t);
lon = cos(t);
x = t;
y = exp(t);
M = [lat',lon',x',y'];

figure()
whos

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(M(:,1),M(:,2),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,1)','YDataSource','M(:,2)');
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(M(:,3),M(:,4),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,3)','YDataSource','M(:,4)');

%linkdata on
%linkdata showdialog
end
```

[image]

However, if I toggle `linkdata on`, the plot completely changes to this.
[image]

How can I preserve the original plot while enabling linking them?

As a last remark: I would obviously want to call that function with arguments (`lat`, `lon`, `x`, `y`) later on. But for this MWE, I thought it would be easier this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `BrushData` property with brush's `ActionPostCallback`. The `BrushData` property is a `uint8` array of `0`s and `1`s, with `1`s indicating data points that are selected. In the callback function, set the `BrushData` of both subplots simultaneously when either of them is "brushed".

```
function linkedexample()
    t = linspace(-2,2,100);
    lat = sin(t);
    lon = cos(t);
    x = t;
    y = exp(t);

    fig = figure();
    subplot(1,2,1)
    p1 = plot(lat,lon);
    subplot(1,2,2)
    p2 = plot(x,y);

    % Bind callback function with the brush
    b = brush(fig);
    b.ActionPostCallback = {@onBrushAction};

    % callback function
    function onBrushAction(~, eventdata)
        set(p1, 'BrushData', eventdata.Axes.Children.BrushData)
        set(p2, 'BrushData', eventdata.Axes.Children.BrushData)
    end
end
```

The result:
[image: Sync brush highlight of subplots]

These two articles, ["Accessing plot brushed data"](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/accessing-plot-brushed-data) on *Undocumented Matlab* and this [Mathwork post by its staff](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/385226-how-to-use-the-data-brush-tool-to-automatically-save-selected-points-in-multiple-line-plots), provide more information about `BrushData` and `ActionPostCallback`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! I only changed two lines: `b.ActionPostCallback = {@onBrushAction,p1, p2};` and `function onBrushAction(~,eventdata,p1,p2)` since I moved the `onBrushAction` function out of the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Rather than linkdata, a callback function that responds to a click input would be more natural to me.

The solution below is a quick hack -- you'd always need to select a point in subplot 1. It can be made more fancy by using MATLAB's ButtonDownFcn function and by defining a callback that understands which subplot has been selected.

```
close all
clearvars

t = linspace(-2,2,100);
lat = sin(t);
lon = cos(t);
x = t;
y = exp(t);
M = [lat',lon',x',y'];

figure(1);

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(M(:,1),M(:,2),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,1)','YDataSource','M(:,2)');
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(M(:,3),M(:,4),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,3)','YDataSource','M(:,4)');

% Quick hack
while 1
    
    % Get coordinates of clicked point
    waitforbuttonpress;
    CP = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
    x1 = CP(2,1);  % X-point
    y1 = CP(2,2);  % Y-point

    % Find index of closest point
    dists = (M(:,1)-x1).^2 + (M(:,2)-y1).^2; 
    [~,idx] = min(dists);

    % Replot base-figure to remove previously selected points
    figure(1);
    subplot(1,2,1)
    plot(M(:,1),M(:,2),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,1)','YDataSource','M(:,2)');
    subplot(1,2,2)
    plot(M(:,3),M(:,4),'-x','XDataSource','M(:,3)','YDataSource','M(:,4)');


    % Update both subplots
    subplot(1,2,1)
    hold on
    plot(M(idx,1),M(idx,2),'ro');
    hold off
    subplot(1,2,2)
    hold on
    plot(M(idx,3),M(idx,4),'ro');
    hold off
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I like it, redrawing shouldn't be a problem either, it's not a lot of data. The only downside is that I can now only use the brush for a single point, not multiple. Would you know a way around this?